# Calling url assigned in a var

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, raphael

While playing around with [Raphael.js Australia map](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html), I tried assigning URLs for each element by changing their attribute in the end of the path:

```
country.cityone = R.path("coordinates").attr({href: "cityone.html"}).attr(attr);
country.citytwo = R.path("coordinates").attr({href: "citytwo.html"}).attr(attr);
...
```

The above works with Firefox, Chrome etc, but IE6-IE9 have trouble with that declaration.

So I thought of declaring another variable after `var country` and assigning the urls to that:

```
var url = {};
url.cityone = "cityone.html";
url.citytwo = "citytwo.html";
```

then calling it on mouse click/down:

```
    st[0].onmousedown = function() {

    current && country[current] && document.getElementById(“current”).appendChild(url);

    };
```

However it won't work at all. Apparently I'm not making the call properly from the function, to relate each URL to its respective city. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure you should just do away with the href and add a mouse event:

```
country.cityone = R.path("coordinates").attr(attr).click(function(){
  window.location.href = "cityone.html";
});
```

I'm pretty sure that will work.

Comment: I just gave it a try, again IE doesn't open up the page provided in href. Tried in a laptop with IE6 and in a desktop with IE9. In Chrome works fine. Maybe IE has some trouble interpreting the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this question, after several trials, I ended up finding out that IE requires a double-click on `click(function(){` for the href page to open up

I found out that in the above code:

```
country.cityone = R.path("coordinates").attr(attr).click(function(){
  window.location.href = "cityone.html";
});
```

I had to change the `.click(function(){` into `.mousedown(function(){` for IE to work as it should.

Thank you @Zevan!
Cheers